# drag & drop over HTML object tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div containing an pdf object and a draggable text:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}


function drop(ev) { alert("DROP"); }
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<object type="application/pdf"  ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"
    data="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
    width="80%"
    height="80%">
</object>
</div>
<br>
<div draggable="true">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The PDF renderes fine but I cannot drop over the PDF object
I can drop fine in the rest of the div

Are there restrictions about drag&drop over html object tags ?
Is there a way around this ?

Comment: You might want to look at [`draggable="true"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_draggable.asp)

Comment: thanks Jack, the problem is not dragging as I can drag into other targets, the problem is the drop _target_ when it is an object tag

Comment: Sorry, I missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up quite involved, here is an outline:

- position the pdf object using `position:absolute`
- create a sibling mask div covering the pdf object using: `position:absolute;z-index:100;background:transparent;pointer-events:none;`
- make the mask div droppable and add events for adding/removing `pointer-events`:

```
$(`#pdfmask`).droppable({
  accept: ...,
  drop: (event, ui) => ...
  activate: (event, ui) => $(`#pdfmask`).css('pointer-events', 'auto'),
  deactivate: (event, ui) => $(`#pdfmask`).css('pointer-events', 'none'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not entirely sure what went wrong for you, but there are a couple of reasons why you might not be able to drag and drop over the PDF object.

First of all, I assume PDFs are treated similar to iframes and are sandboxed - you can't detect mouse events over iframes or PDFs. Because of this, you won't be able to detect your mouse position when it is over the PDF.

A solution to this problem would be to position an element over the PDF and have that element be the droppable element, however, it seems as if you are already doing this in your code. The PDF is contained within the parent element `#mydiv`, which means something else is the problem.

Another possible issue is that your draggable element is larger than the droppable element. It will sometimes only accept the drop if the draggable element is fully within the bounds of the droppable element.

To conclude, I assume something is wrong with your code outside the section provided as I managed to get it working without many issues.

The following code snippet works for me in Chrome, however if something seems to be different for you, I can look into it.

Note -- It appears your code was modified after writing, so if you need help with that let me know.

```js
$("#Thumbs li").draggable();
$('#mydiv').droppable({
  accept: '#Thumbs li',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log('Dropped');
  }
});
```

```css
object {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#mydiv {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#Thumbs li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="mydiv">
  <object id="object" data="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
    type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>

<ul id="Thumbs">
  <li>foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
</ul>
```